# Error/Crash when react project page is refreshed but not on initial page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-router-dom

so I am building a React Firebase Notes App I designed a profile page but I keep getting blank screen/error in the console when I refresh the page but as the GIF shows I don't get the error on initial load and the page functions just fine. I am not exactly what is causing the error so any help on how to fix it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Error message:

```
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

```
The above error occurred in the <Profile> component:
```

My code in the profile component:

```
function Profile() {
  const { user } = useContext(AppContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      navigate('/');
    } else {
      navigate('/profile');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <m.div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-8 p-5" initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
      <UpdateName />
      {user?.providerData[0]?.providerId === 'password' ? (
        <>
          <UpdateEmail />
          <UpdatePassword />
        </>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
      <Logout />
      <DeleteAccount />
    </m.div>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

Snippet of my router code:

```
 <AppProvider>
      <LazyMotion features={domAnimation}>
        <div className="App">
          <main>
            <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
              <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname} initial={true}>
                <Route
                  path="/profile"
                  element={
                    <React.Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
                      <Profile />
                    </React.Suspense>
                  }
                />
              </Routes>
            </AnimatePresence>
          </main>
          <ToastContainer />
        </div>
      </LazyMotion>
    </AppProvider>
```

[image: GIF of The Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `user.providerData` is an undefined array reference. You should use the Optional Chaining operator on the `providerData` array access as well.

Example:

```
user.providerData?.[0]?.providerId === 'password'
```

Comment: Oh wow can't believe I missed that. I have been banging my head against a wall trying to figure out what's wrong lol. Thank you so much.